# How to identify big o complexity of a function

Tags: complexity-theory

So this expression represents the running time: `f = 3N^2 + 6.`

How do I identify its primary/secondary efficiencies? and how do I know what Big O complexity class it is?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is should be asked on [cs.se]

Comment: What are primary/secondary efficiencies? Never heard of that before. Is that well-known terminology?

Answer (score 0):

For the function you have given that is `O(n^2)`.

In the general case, if the function is a polynomial, you take the highest power and drop the coefficient.

If the function includes an exponential term, that will always dominate any polynomial.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more details.